# Terraform Module fails when attempting to build more than one VM in azure

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a main.tf, variable.tf, and can refrence it from a /module file called vms.tf using source 
        ../.

However, if i try and build more than one VM the second VM keeps tossing an error like:
        Error: Missing required argument

```
    on vms.tf line 6, in module "bar":
    6: module "bar" {

    The argument "client_id" is required, but no definition was found.
```

The first VM will build fine if i only build one, but soon as i add more vm's to my module it acts as if the credentials aren't there. I've tried adding them directly under the provider in addition to the environment variables, no dice.

My calling module looks like this and is in a folder by itself:

```
        module "foo" {
            source   = "../."
            location = "westus"
            prefix   = "skachar"
        }
        module "bar" {
            source   = "../."
            prefix   = "skachar2"
            location = "eastus"
        }
```

The below code I added as requested by someone in the comment section. Its my main.tf file that resides in the folder below where my module is located. I'm going to add my variable.tf file as well just for the sake of being thorough. It'll be down below the main.tf file which is the code you see right below this paragraph. I'd really like to figure out why the second VM bombs out. I'm providing it a unique prefix and the error message just doesn't make any sense. If there was no credentials then the first VM wouldn't provision. Anywho, if someone could point me in the right direction, perhaps there is some documentation I'm missing somewhere. Thanks for any help provided.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>1.28.0"
  # subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"
  # client_id       = "${var.client_id}"
  # client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"
  # tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"

}

# Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}TFRG"
  location = "${var.location}"
  tags     = "${var.tags}"
}

# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}TFVnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  tags                = "${var.tags}"
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}TFSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

# Create public IP
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "publicip" {
  name                         = "${var.prefix}TFPublicIP"
  location                     = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  tags                         = "${var.tags}"
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}TFNSG"
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  tags                = "${var.tags}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                      = "${var.prefix}NIC"
  location                  = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id}"
  tags                      = "${var.tags}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.prefix}NICConfg"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.id}"
  }
}

# Create a Linux virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}TFVM"
  location              = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.nic.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2S_v3"
  tags                  = "${var.tags}"

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${var.prefix}OsDisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "${lookup(var.sku, var.location)}"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.prefix}TFVM"
    admin_username = "skachar"
    admin_password = "emptyforpostonstackoverflow"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

}

output "ip" {
  value = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.ip_address}"
}

output "os_sku" {
  value = "${lookup(var.sku, var.location)}"
}
```

What follows here is the variables.tf file.

```
variable "location" {}

variable "prefix" {
    type = "string"
    # default = "skachar"
}

variable "tags" {
    type = "map"

    default = {
        Environment = "Terraform GS"
        Dept = "Engineering"
  }
}

variable "sku" {
    default = {
        westus = "16.04-LTS"
        eastus = "18.04-LTS"
    }
}

# variable "subscription_id" {}
# variable "client_id" {}
# variable "client_secret" {}
# variable "tenant_id" {}
```

FYI - I ran the build of a single VM and it built without issue....well I had to provide a proper password, but everything else went off without a hitch. Again would appreciate any help anyone could provide.
Cheers,
-Sam

Comment: Can you show the module files and the main.tf file?

Comment: Added all requested content.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate your suggestion on using count for looping through the creation of multiple resources, I'm familiar with count and it's useful...

However as i stated in my initial post, I was getting an error message surrounding creds. I've resolved the issue. I discovered by changing VS Code from PowerShell to PowerShell Integrated Console that loading your env variables there will allow you to use a module like the one I have posted. No clue why the first drop down doesn't work for multiple resources.

Should anyone run into this issue just make certain you select the second PowerShell environment in the VS Code terminal drop down when you set your environment variables. Including a snippet for clarification on what I'm talking about.
[PowerShell Integrated Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJspN.png)
Cheers,
-Sam